# Where is the python interpreter installed when ssh to a remote machine

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm a little confused with this scenario about which python interpreter is used:

I use vscode to ssh to the python codes in a remote machine, and then I installed the python interpreter as VScode suggests. I was wondering which machine is the python interpreter installed. The remote machine or my local machine? I think it's the remote one, but not 100% sure.

Comment: Well ... the python interpreter needs to be installed on the machine where you are running the Python code.  If you are running on a remote machine, that's where VS Code needs to put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use VSCode to SSH into a remote machine and install a Python interpreter as suggested by VSCode, the interpreter is installed on the remote machine, not on your local machine. VSCode simply acts as an interface to interact with the remote environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you performed the operation on a remote machine, it is installed on the remote machine.

You can also use the following code to output the path of the current interpreter.

```py
import os
import sys

executable_path = sys.executable
install_path = os.path.dirname(executable_path)

print("Python executable path:", executable_path)
print("Python install path:", install_path)
```

More info:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial